# Clevertap type error, cannot set properties of undefined(setting "getCleverTapID")

Tags: javascript, web, clevertap

I am using clevertap Javascript code for my app, but I am getting type errors, can anyone please help
here is the code I am using for web integration from their documentation

```
     var clevertap = {event:[], profile:[], account:[], onUserLogin:[], notifications:[], privacy:[]};
 // replace with the CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID with the actual ACCOUNT ID value from your Dashboard -> Settings page
clevertap.account.push({"id": "CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID"});
clevertap.privacy.push({optOut: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user of the device opts out of sharing their data
clevertap.privacy.push({useIP: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user agrees to share their IP data
 (function () {
         var wzrk = document.createElement('script');
         wzrk.type = 'text/javascript';
         wzrk.async = true;
         wzrk.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net' : 'http://static.clevertap.com') + '/js/a.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         s.parentNode.insertBefore(wzrk, s);
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the script expect a `window.clevertap` or `window.wizrocket` object initialized before it loads itself.

Most possible cause of this behavior is that your `var clevertap` is not global.

**Solution:**

You could use `window.clevertap` instead of `var clevertap`, so your script will look like this now

```
window.clevertap = {event:[], profile:[], account:[], onUserLogin:[], notifications:[], privacy:[]};
 // replace with the CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID with the actual ACCOUNT ID value from your Dashboard -> Settings page
window.clevertap.account.push({"id": "CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID"});
window.clevertap.privacy.push({optOut: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user of the device opts out of sharing their data
window.clevertap.privacy.push({useIP: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user agrees to share their IP data
 (function () {
         var wzrk = document.createElement('script');
         wzrk.type = 'text/javascript';
         wzrk.async = true;
         wzrk.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net' : 'http://static.clevertap.com') + '/js/a.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         s.parentNode.insertBefore(wzrk, s);
  })();
```